# pass R data as input to html?

Tags: html, r, google-maps-api-3

I have an R list

```
list[[1]]
   [1] 5720 JACKSONBURG RD,TRENTON,OH,45067
   [2] 1282 OAKMONT AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45013  
   [3] 1001 CHASE AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45015   
   [4] 2266 TWIN OAKS DR,LEBANON,OH,45036
```

And I created google map in javascript with HTML.
I use the above address as input (manually) for the value in HTML:

```
 <select multiple id="waypoints">

      <option value="5720 JACKSONBURG RD,TRENTON,OH">1</option>
      <option value="1282 OAKMONT AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45013 ">2</option>
      <option value="1001 CHASE AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45015">3</option>
      <option value="2266 TWIN OAKS DR,LEBANON,OH,45036">4</option>
```

Is there a way to generate 
`<option value="XXXXX">`
based on the R data I have? Like a loop? 
I am following https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use `xmlNode()` from the *XML* package. Here we can also use it with `lapply()` in the `.children` argument to produce the children nodes in the same call.

```
library(XML)

xmlNode(
    "select multiple", 
    attrs = c(id = "waypoints"),
    .children = lapply(seq_along(x[[1]]), function(i) {
        xmlNode("option", i, attrs = c(value = x[[1]][i]))
    })
)
# <select multiple id="waypoints">
#  <option value="5720 JACKSONBURG RD,TRENTON,OH,45067">1</option>
#  <option value="1282 OAKMONT AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45013">2</option>
#  <option value="1001 CHASE AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45015">3</option>
#  <option value="2266 TWIN OAKS DR,LEBANON,OH,45036">4</option>
# </select multiple>
```

**Data:**

```
x <- list(c("5720 JACKSONBURG RD,TRENTON,OH,45067", "1282 OAKMONT AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45013", 
"1001 CHASE AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45015", "2266 TWIN OAKS DR,LEBANON,OH,45036"
))
```

Comment: yep. how to insert to html?

Comment: Okay @EskimoT - I fixed it.  What do you mean by "insert to html"?

Comment: <select multiple id="waypoints"> is a selection box in the webpage. How do I auto insert xmlNode() output in to a html part.  It won't work if I just put xmlNode() in the html part.

Comment: @EskimoT - I don't know the answer to that.  I will have to research it.  It will take me a little while.

Comment: @EskimoT - I think you want `addNode()`.  See the help file at `?addNode`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to build the HTML, you can do that with paste(). With your sample data (which looks like a list containing a vector)

```
x<-list(c("5720 JACKSONBURG RD,TRENTON,OH,45067",
   "1282 OAKMONT AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45013",
   "1001 CHASE AVE,HAMILTON,OH,45015",
   "2266 TWIN OAKS DR,LEBANON,OH,45036"))
```

You can do

```
paste0("<option value=\"", x[[1]], "\">",seq_along(x[[1]]),"</option>", collapse="")
```

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is how do I use put this paste0 output under  <select multiple id="waypoints">

Comment: Just paste() that value in as well using an additional paste()

Comment: I think this is a html issue, since I cannot run r with html, the paste0 results cannot be directly used as   <option value="XXXXX">. I try to put paste0() under <select multiple id="waypoints"> and it does not work.